# Import external Typescript file in Next.js app

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js

I have a Next.js app `A` with only Typescript files and a package `B` with this `index.tsx` file:

```
export default () => {
    console.log('hi');
}
```

When I import it in any file of my Next.js app A by doing:

```
import f from 'B';
```

I get this error:

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

that seems related to Webpack but I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: I'm having the same difficulties. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I opened an issue in their repo: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9303 . It seems to be a known issue

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450928/nextjs-import-external-components-from-parent-directory

Answer (score 2):

You can add `transpilePackages: ['package-name'],` into your next.config.js starting from 13.0 version
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/transpilePackages
If you're using older version of next.js, you can use this [package](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules/), but it's deprecated