# Nextjs import external components from parent directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, vercel

I have external directory `common` and I would like to import react components from that directory into `web-static`. In `web-static` I am using nextjs.

[image]

Currently I having this error:

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/jakub/Sites/WORK/wilio-web-common/common/src/@vendor/atoms'`

I added these lines to `next.config.js`:

```
const babeRule = config.module.rules[babelRuleIndex];
if (babeRule && babeRule.test) {
  babeRule.test = /\.(web\.)?(tsx|ts|js|mjs|jsx)$/;
  if (babeRule.include) {
    babeRule.include = [
      ...babeRule.include,
      resolve(__dirname, "../common/src/@vendor"),
    ];
  }
}
```

```
config.resolve.alias = {
  ...config.resolve.alias,
  "@vendor": resolve(__dirname, "../common/src/@vendor")
};
```

My `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"paths": {
  "@vendor/*": ["../common/src/@vendor/*"]
}
```

Webpack can resolve these components but can't resolve installed packages in these components.

```
../common/src/@vendor/atoms/Test.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/user1/Sites/WORK/web-app/common/src/@vendor/atoms'
```

Do I need to include this directory also in webpacks `config.externals`? Current nextjs webpack `externals`

```
-----
options.isServer: false
[ 'next' ]
-----
-----
options.isServer: true
[ [Function] ]
-----
```

How can be this done? Thanks for any help

Comment: how do you want to consume those react components? via script tag?
Cause then you can add an entry point that compiles all of them and outputs its asset to web-static

Comment: Via `import` statement

Comment: So why is it important for all output files to be in web-static? Why not just import them from their location? What is the advantages in having web-static folder?

Comment: What output files? Web-static directory is nextjs app. I want to import react components from external directory `../common` into nextjs directory.

Comment: Okay. By output files I mean webpack chunks. Good luck, hope you find your answer. Apparently I lack knowledge in nextJs platform

Answer (score 20):

Starting in Next.js 10.1.2, you can use the currently [experimental](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9474#issuecomment-810212174) `externalDir` option in **next.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    externalDir: true,
  },
};
```

Note that for React components to work, I also had to declare the root **package.json** as a [yarn workspace](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/):

```
{
  // ...
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": ["next-js-directory"],
  // ...
}
```

Comment: for me this worked without the need to add workspaces to my package.json

Comment: for me too experimental option worked along with dynamic import of parent component inside child component.
const Header = dynamic(import('../../home/components/Header.js'));

Comment: Using `externalDir` bundles duplicate versions of dependencies. If your next site and your external dependency both `import React`, then you'll get two React libraries bundled which breaks the component. No one uses Yarn anymore so that's not a viable option

Comment: Thank you. My problem was that I was trying to import a typescript interface from outside the /src directory and was getting an error along the lines of `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file`. Setting `externalDir` to true solved it, didn't need to set any workspaces